# סוֹף פָּסוּק‎ Sof pasuq cantillation mark

Tags: hebrew, hebrew-bible, masoretic-text, bible-versions

[image: MT of Gn 22 sof pasuq right of yellow highlights]What's the earliest evidence of the סוֹף פָּסוּק‎ [Sof pasuq] cantillation mark? Did I correctly identify the sof pasuq right of my yellow highlights (the two dots vertical dots that look like a colon "׃‬")? Does it indicate a verse ending? Do current Bible versions divide their verses based on this mark?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_cantillation